# Не работает CSS файл когда ссылаюсь на него из html и открываю страницу. golang, html, css

Tags: html, css, golang

Структура
[image: Структура]

Не работает css когда перехожу на свой сайт - Вижу скелет страницы.
Я уже всё перепробовал, и уже бомбит, думаю перейти на JS если через как минимум 3 дня не смогу решить эту проблему.

Вот я подключаю css файлы.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../../Frontend/register/css/gl.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../../Frontend/register/css/bootstrap.css">
```

Какая она сейчас(скелет).
[image: изображение]
Какая должна быть страница.
[image: изображение]

Comment: С путями явно что то не то. А вы не хотите сделать папку `static` или `templates`и в нее перенести все стили. Тогда пути всегда будут идти относительно этой папки.

Comment: Я разобрался уже, просто надо было в http.Dir еще одну точку добавить, но спасибо за ответ, я рад что stackoverflow такое отзывчивое сообщество.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если у кого возникла такая же проблема, вот вам готовое решение, чтобы вы тоже не парились с только же сколько и я.

```
//Мои пути
http.Handle("/css/", http.StripPrefix("/css/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("./css/"))))
```